# Session state wrapper, extending an existing application

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, generics, session

I'm adding additional functionality to an existing MVC .net application, and to help prevent or at least reduce repeated reads to the dB I'm dumping a few custom entities in session. I'm limiting what can be stored in session to say a max of 5 objects for now.

Given below is the code and it seems generic enough and works fine locally on my box; any suggestions to improve this and session is In-Proc but if it does get stored in a persistent medium say SQL server then I would need to customize this further - decorate custom object properties w/XML element attributes

```
public class QuestionModelSessionStateProvider : IQuestionModelSessionStateProvider
{
    const int MaxSize = 5;

    public T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        HttpSessionState session = GetSessionState();

        T returnValue = default(T);

        if (session == null) return returnValue;

        if (session["QuestionModelStore"] != null)
        {
            var questionModelStore = (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>)session["QuestionModelStore"];
            foreach (var t in questionModelStore.Where(t => t.Key.Equals(key)))
            {
                returnValue = t.Value;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }


    public void SetValue<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        HttpSessionState session = GetSessionState();

        if (session == null) return;

        List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> questionModelStore;

        if (session["QuestionModelStore"] == null)
        {
            questionModelStore = new List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> { new KeyValuePair<string, T>(key, value) };
            session["QuestionModelStore"] = questionModelStore;
        }
        else
        {
            questionModelStore = (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>)session["QuestionModelStore"];
            questionModelStore.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, T>(key, value));
        }

        if (questionModelStore.Count > MaxSize)
        {
            questionModelStore.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }


    public void RemoveValue<T>(string key)
    {
        HttpSessionState session = GetSessionState();
        int indexToRemoveAt = 0;
        var found = false;
        if (session != null && session["QuestionModelStore"] != null)
        {
            var questionModelStore = (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>) session["QuestionModelStore"];
            for (var i = 0; i < questionModelStore.Count; i++)
            {
                if (questionModelStore[i].Key.Equals(key))
                {
                    indexToRemoveAt = i;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found)
                questionModelStore.RemoveAt(indexToRemoveAt);
        }
    }


    public void Clear()
    {
        HttpSessionState session = GetSessionState();
        if (session != null)
        {
            session["QuestionModelStore"] = null;
        }
    }


    public int Count<T>()
    {

        HttpSessionState session = GetSessionState();
        if (session != null)
        {
            //return session.Count;
            if (session["QuestionModelStore"] != null)
            {
                var questionModelStore = (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>)session["QuestionModelStore"];
                return questionModelStore.Count;
            }

        }

        return 0;

    }



    private static HttpSessionState GetSessionState()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            return HttpContext.Current.Session;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 places where you have code like,

```
if (session != null)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> questionModelStore;

    if (session["QuestionModelStore"] == null)
    {
        questionModelStore = (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>)session["QuestionModelStore"];
```

It would be neater if these were a common subroutine:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> GetQuestionModelStore<T>()
{
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    if (!session)
        return null;
    return (List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>)session["QuestionModelStore"];
}
```

That would simplify code such as:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    var cached = GetQuestionModelStore();
    if (cached == null)
        return default(T);
    return cached.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key.Equals(key));
}
```

It might be slightly faster to use a Queue than a List, because a Queue is designed to let you enqueue at one end and dequeue at the other.

You're not quite implementing a LRU algorithm: if you want to do that, when you find an item in the cache you should move the item to the most-recently-used end of the list.

There's one bug I see, which is that your methods are generic: the first time you call SetValue it creates a `List<KeyValuePair<string, T>>`; unless all your SetValue and GetValue methods use the same type of T this will cause a run-time error (casting between different types of T). If all your SetValue and GetValue methods do use the same type of T then you might as well specify what T is instead of making it generic.